# Data recovery and defragmentation

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I recently lost all my Windows data. I tried running **Photorec** and I was able to recover some 18 GB of data back. Photorec threw an error after recovering 18 GB stating **"Segmentation Fault"**. Was it because my windows drive was hardly ever defragged? If so, what routines/precautions I can take to make sure if something like this happens again on Windows or Linux side, Photorec wont throw the **"Segmentation Fault"** error.(Of course one precaution being backing up data regularly :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Segmentation Fault is usually a programming error. There's nothing you can do about but always upgrade to the newest version and sending a bug report to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is unrelated to the problem with the hard drive. It indicates something went wrong with the software you were using at the time, possibly photorec itself.

Options:

- Use a newer version of photorec as it may have fixed that problem
- Use testdisk, which is a tool from the same author as photorec and can do similar things, though it may be slightly harder to use.
- Try photorec again; it may not happen the next time.